# How to i can remove coupon code and Flat rate from checkout in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento2 - I want to **Remove / Disabled Flat rate and Discount from cart and Checkout page** ?

How to i can do this ?

Please check below screenshot.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to goto admin and than follow below steps :

Disabled flat rate via **store > configuration > sales > shipping method**

You can try and check:

**rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ **

**rm -rf pub/static**

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

**hope its work for you**